# Tkinter Canvas game needs a slight rework

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here's the Code firstly - I'll get into the problems after. Although I'm sure you can spot plenty without needing to scroll to far down.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import math
import time

test = random.randint(10,40)
print(test)

class Game():
    global x0,y0,x1,y1,Game,debug, Player, mousex0, mousey0, mousex1,
           mousey1, moveTowardMouse, rayCast, speed, frayCast, fx0, fy0,
           fx1, fy1, Food
    def move(event):
        global x0,y0,x1,y1,mouseX0,mouseY0,mouseX1,mouseY1,fx0, fy0,
              fx1, fy1,Food
        mouseX0 = event.x - 10
        mouseY0 = event.y - 10
        mouseX1 = event.x + 10
        mouseY1 = event.y + 10
        Game.coords(rayCast, x0, y0, mouseX1, mouseY1)
        if x0 != mouseX0 and x0 < mouseX0:
            x0 = x0 + speed
            x1 = x1 + speed
            Game.coords(Player, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        if x0 != mouseX0 and x0 > mouseX0:
            x0 = x0 - speed
            x1 = x1 - speed
            Game.coords(Player, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        if y0 != mouseY0 and y0 < mouseY0:
            y0 = y0 + speed
            y1 = y1 + speed
            Game.coords(Player, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        if y0 != mouseY0 and y0 > mouseY0:
            y0 = y0 - speed
            y1 = y1 - speed
            Game.coords(Player, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        Game.coords(frayCast, x0,y0, fx0,fy0)
        if fx0 > x0 and (fx0 - x0) < 20:
            fx0 = fx0 + 0.5
            fx1 = fx1 + 0.5
            Game.coords(Food, fx0,fy0,fx1,fy1)
        if fx0 < x0 and (fx0 + x0) < 20:
            fx0 = fx0 - 0.5
            fx1 = fx1 - 0.5
            Game.coords(Food, fx0,fy0,fx1,fy1)
        if fy0 > y0 and (fy0 - y0) < 20:
            fy0 = fy0 + 0.5
            fy1 = fy1 + 0.5
            Game.coords(Food, fx0,fy0,fx1,fy1)
        if fy0 < y0 and (fy0 - y0) < 20:
            fy0 = fy0 - 0.5
            fy1 = fy1 - 0.5
            Game.coords(Food, fx0,fy0,fx1,fy1)
        if fx0 > x0 and (fx0 - x0) < 5:
            if fy0 > y0 and (fy0 - y0) <5:
                Game.delete(Food)
                x0 = x0 - fx1
                y0 = y0 - fy1
                Game.coords(Player, x0,y0,x1,y1)

    fx0 = 20
    fy0 = 20
    fx1 = test + 20
    fy1 = test + 20
    x0 = -50
    y0 = -50
    x1 = 50
    y1 = 50
    speed = 1
    mouseX0 = 0
    mouseY0 = 0
    mouseX1 = 0
    mouseY1 = 0
    debug = "DEBUGGED"
    module = Tk()
    Game = Canvas(module, width=1000, height=1000)
    Player = Game.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill="blue")
    Food = Game.create_oval(fx0, fy0, fx1, fy1, fill="red")
    rayCast = Game.create_line(x0,y0,mouseX1,mouseY1)
    frayCast = Game.create_line(x0,y0,mouseX1,mouseY1)
    module.bind('<Motion>', move)
    Game.pack()
    module.mainloop()
```

So I'm having just a slight "oh snap" just a moment ago when I realised that my code was basically useless.

In the game I'm creating, I'm wanting the Player controlled sprite on the canvas to move at a slow speed towards the mouse. I googled how to get the mouse coordinates, it told me that I could use the  event to get the coords in a function. However since getting those coords I've slowly put all the major sprite movement calculations in the same function resulting in a functional game... that only does something as long as your moving the mouse.

The idea is that the NPC-sprite is a random size and spawns in a random space on the canvas. It moves in random directions in a slow speed until it is within "20" of the player controlled sprite, in which case it moves (faster) away from the player-controlled sprite.

Aside from the fact that all this only happens when you move the mouse (and that I'm still using raycasting to get a trajectory for the sprites to follow, there are a few more issues I need help with.

Firstly, the random size of the NPC sprite works great. But it spawns exactly the same place every time.

Secondly, the NPC's "avoid the player" code seems to be... less than functional. Basically it works fine, but then it just keeps working even after the player has moved "20" away from the sprite.

Lastly, I'm having an issue with the coords of the sprites themselves. You see the raycasting reveals that the true coords for the sprites are not in the centre of their canvas representation of a circle, but instead in the top left corner of what would be an invisible square around said circle. I need this to be in the centre of the sprite rather than not otherwise the gameplay mechanics become a little bit buggy.

Back to the biggest issue (With the way updates work for sprite coords) I'm fine with setting up like Updates per Tick within the game and run all my calculations every tick, but then I wouldn't know how to get the mouse coords outside of using that event.

Long story short some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the universal widget method [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) to schedule a function to be called after a specified delay. Calling it repeatedly at the end of that function would be a way to get some "ticks" going in your game which Should be very helpful for implementing the animation you want.

Comment: As for the issues with coordinates, since your "sprites" are `Canvas` oval objects, they're defined by a bounding-box given by the coordinates (x0, y0) of the top left corner and the coordinates (x1, y1) of a point just outside of the bottom right corner. To find the center of it just calculate the average x and y value: i.e it's the point at position `(x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your improved code. I explained everything in the comments.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import math
import time

class Game():

    # This __init__ will run first when you run Game()
    # Learn to always set up your programs this way.
    def __init__(self):

        test = random.randint(10,40)
        print(test)

        # Put self. before the name of every variable you might want to use outside this __init__ function.
        # this way you don't need to define them separately in every function

        # You defined these xs and ys by hand so of course it remains in the same position.
        # define them randomly and you'll be fine.
        self.fx0 = 20 
        self.fy0 = 20 
        self.fx1 = test + 20
        self.fy1 = test + 20
        self.x0 = -50
        self.y0 = -50
        self.x1 = 50
        self.y1 = 50
        self.speed = 1
        self.mouseX0 = 0
        self.mouseY0 = 0
        self.mouseX1 = 0
        self.mouseY1 = 0
        self.debug = "DEBUGGED"

        # Added these two variables
        self.tick_intervals = 10
        self.food_exists = True

        self.module = Tk()

        #Game is the name of your class don't use it here: (use game instead)
        self.game = Canvas(self.module, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.Player = self.game.create_oval(self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1,fill="blue")
        self.Food = self.game.create_oval(self.fx0, self.fy0, self.fx1, self.fy1, fill="red")
        self.rayCast = self.game.create_line(self.x0,self.y0,self.mouseX1,self.mouseY1)
        self.frayCast = self.game.create_line(self.x0,self.y0,self.mouseX1,self.mouseY1)
        self.game.pack()
        self.move()
        self.module.mainloop()


    def move(self):
        # To get mouse position on your whole screen: .winfo_pointerx() and .winfo_pointery()
        # To get position of widget (self.game) on screen .winfo_rootx()
        # x and y below are the same as mouse event.x and event.y without the need to bind anything to self.module
        x = self.game.winfo_pointerx()-self.game.winfo_rootx()
        y = self.game.winfo_pointery()-self.game.winfo_rooty()

        # If you have a value you use more than 1 time,
        # it's best to define it first then put that here
        # instead of writing it out every time.
        # this way you can change it very easily
        # better define these in __init__ function with self.something = ...
        self.mouseX0 = x - 10 # define var for 10 
        self.mouseY0 = y - 10
        self.mouseX1 = x + 10
        self.mouseY1 = y + 10

        # You should also design a (visible or invisible) wall around the screen
        # so your Player and Food can't run off the screen.
        # Basically it's numbers and some if statements.

        # If you don't put elif here x and y might get resized then resized again.
        # but you only need to resize them once a tick.
        # You don't need != here. < > are enough.
        # Look up += -= *= /= functions.   
        if self.x0 < self.mouseX0:
            self.x0 += self.speed
            self.x1 += self.speed
        elif self.x0 > self.mouseX0:
            self.x0 -= self.speed
            self.x1 -= self.speed
        if self.y0 < self.mouseY0:
            self.y0 += self.speed
            self.y1 += self.speed
        elif self.y0 > self.mouseY0:
            self.y0 -= self.speed
            self.y1 -= self.speed

        # Need to call these once a tick and not every time you change x or y
        self.game.coords(self.rayCast, self.x0, self.y0, self.mouseX1, self.mouseY1)
        self.game.coords(self.Player,self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1)

        # After you eat food this shouldn't run any more.
        # This is why Player kept getting bigger and bigger
        if self.food_exists:
            if self.fx0 > self.x0 and (self.fx0 - self.x0) < 20: # define var for 20
                self.fx0 += 0.5 # define var for 0.5
                self.fx1 += 0.5
            elif self.fx0 < self.x0 and (self.fx0 + self.x0) < 20:
                self.fx0 -= 0.5
                self.fx1 -= 0.5
            if self.fy0 > self.y0 and (self.fy0 - self.y0) < 20:
                self.fy0 += 0.5
                self.fy1 += 0.5
            elif self.fy0 < self.y0 and (self.fy0 - self.y0) < 20:
                self.fy0 -= 0.5
                self.fy1 -= 0.5
            if self.fx0 > self.x0 and (self.fx0 - self.x0) < 5: # define var for 5
                if self.fy0 > self.y0 and (self.fy0 - self.y0) <5:
                    self.game.delete(self.Food)
                    self.x0 -= self.fx1
                    self.y0 -= self.fy1
                    self.food_exists = False
            self.game.coords(self.Food,self.fx0,self.fy0,self.fx1,self.fy1)
            self.game.coords(self.frayCast, self.x0,self.y0, self.fx0,self.fy0)

        # This automatically runs self.move after (self.tick_intevals) miliseconds
        self.game.after(self.tick_intervals,self.move)

# This IF runs the Game() only if you run the script yourself.
# This way if you imported this script into another program it wouldn't run Game() 
# Learn to always use this if for your programs
if __name__=='__main__':
    Game()
```

Comment: Thanks for that mate. The code works great but I'm still having a few issues.

I managed to get the "invisible wall" working fine, for both sprites, however the coordinates of them both still are not centered to their graphical representation.

Are there different x0,y0,x1,y1 integers I can use to make the center of the circle = the center of the sprite? Just makes it difficult for the player when the graphical representation of their player and actual one are centered in different places.

Comment: Well your rayCast  starts at (x0,y0) and frayCast starts at (fx0,fy0). you need to make them start at the center of objects. (x+(width/2),y+(height/2)).

Comment: You might wanna do the same for all of the if statements in move function.

Comment: And instead of x1,y1 create a width and height function in __init__ and just put (x0+w, y0+h) instead of x1,y1. this way you only need to add to x0 or y0 instead of doing it to both x0,y0 and x1,y1. and in the if statements themselves just put x+widht//2, y+height//2 to compare by their center instead of starting coords.